# Let me edit a bounty while it's still active

Tags: feature-request, bounties

I want to change/increase [currently set bounty on my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950382/google-current-place-accuracy-in-ios) but there is no any option to edit bounty.

I would like to have such an option like that, as it will be helpful when a user want to increase his/her bounty when they don't get accurate answer, or not getting more attention on the question etc.

For example, if I set *100 rep bounty* on the question, and on the *third day* if I want to increase bounty on same question to *200* (must be more then previous bounty) so there should be option to increase bounty. So my current bounty will be *300*.

Comment: I've used CLLocationManager and Places API and it looks like you have the answer to your question. If not I think you need to add more details to your question rather than increasing the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is a useful feature. A bounty is sort of advertisement time. No one is going to ask half way 'can I pay more to get the same thing done?'

If you want to increase the bounty, because it didn't get enough attention, increase the bounty after it has expired. Increasing the bounty half way isn't helping in any way. Trying to improve your question is.

Comment: Yes you are right but some time we ignore to see on those questions which has less bounty to others. It's natural. Sometimes question is more important and need fast solution as soon as possible at that time this feature might be helpful not sure.

Comment: @iPatel If it's that important, you should be paying real money for a solution, not virtual internet points.